# C# equivalent of powershell statement

Tags: c#, powershell, active-directory

The following code in Powershell gets me the ntdsaGUID of a DC (for use in repadmin)

```
Get-ADDomainController -filter * | Select-Object -Property Name, IPv4Address, @{n='DsaGuid'; e={(Get-ADObject $_.NTDSSettingsObjectDN).ObjectGUID}}
```

I am having a hard time generating equivalent in C#.

There is a private member on `DomainController` (derived from: `domain.DomainControllers`) called `NtdsaObjectGuid` but I don't know if I can get to that, even though VS can.

Is there a supported way to get the DSA GUID of a DC in C#?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand your question. How do you want to fetch this data with C#? Do you want to reference System.Management.Automation and run your PS one-liner? Or do you want to use the System.DirectoryServices namespace? Note that using the FindAll() method for the System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.DomainController class should give you most of the information (or just do a lookup on the directoryEntry of the specific Domain Controller and retrieve the required property).

Comment: I want to do this in C#.  I can get all the DC's no problem. I just can't get to the DSA GUID of it in C# that I can see.   When I have a DC and inspect it in VS, I can see Non-Public members has "NtdsaObjectGuid"  That's what I want to get to, but as it appears to be non-public, I don't know how....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a helper class as provided by Steinberg in this answer:
[I need to access a non-public member (Highlighted Item) of a Combo Box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031288/i-need-to-access-a-non-public-member-highlighted-item-of-a-combo-box)

This allowed me to get my NtdsaObjectGuid that I needed.