# C# how to access non-public members for NCrontab?

Tags: c#, cron, ncron

How to access non-public members for NCrontab ?

```
string time_A = "20,25,30 20 * * 1-5";
var schedule = NCrontab.CrontabSchedule.Parse(time_A);
```

I can see Non-Public members of 'schedule' from the debug,

but I want to get value of _day and _hours.

- _days {*}   NCrontab.CrontabField
- _daysOfWeek {1-5}   NCrontab.CrontabField
- _hours  {20}    NCrontab.CrontabField
- _minutes    {20,25,30}  NCrontab.CrontabField
- _months {*} NCrontab.CrontabField
      _seconds    null    NCrontab.CrontabField

From [I need to access a non-public member (Highlighted Item) of a Combo Box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031288/i-need-to-access-a-non-public-member-highlighted-item-of-a-combo-box), seems like it does not work for the following line.

```
PropertyInfo highlightedItemProperty = schedule.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic  | BindingFlags.Instance).Single(pi => pi.Name == "_days");
```

Please advise.

**Updated !!!**

I can fix it now.

```
string time_A = "20,25,30 18-22 * * 1-5";
var schedule = CrontabSchedule.Parse(time_A);
var bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance;
var field = schedule.GetType().GetField("_hours", bindingFlags);
var getfield = field.GetValue(schedule);
```

Comment: You can use `typeof(Schedule).GetField(BindingFlags.NonPublic|BindingFlags.Instance)`, fieldName)'. But realize that it is not a good idea to rely on implementation details like this.

Comment: Thank you for providing me the link !!! It can helps me.